# jqGrid data format and jsonReader

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the data in the following format and when binding i get empty rows in my `jqGrid`. What should be my data type or how can i avoid using `jsonReader` so that it will handle it by default.

[image: Data]

My grid structure is,

```
$("#UserReportGrid").jqGrid({

    datatype: 'local',
    data: data,
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colNames,
    localReader: {
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "",
    id: 0, root: "data",
    },
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    pager: '#GridPager',
    caption: "User Details",
    height: 'auto',
    sortname: 'SNo',
    gridview: true
});
```

I have tried,

```
JSON.parse(data) resulted in exception
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))  resulted in same no records are displayed
```

Comment: Just remove the localReader from the settings and be a sure you have set key: true in colModel to identify the column which will act as id. The data should be array of objects and you do not need to JSON.parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of your problem is the usage of wrong `localReader` parameter. You should either replace it to

```
localReader: { id: "SNo" }
```

or to remove it at all and to add `key: true` in the column `SNo`, if you have the column at all in `colModel`.

The exact processing of input data could be different in different versions of jqGrid and in different forks ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) and old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Please include the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the information about the fork in every question about jqGrid.